# Python asyncio task ordering

Tags: python, queue, python-asyncio, event-loop

I have a question about how the event loop in python's `asyncio` module manages outstanding tasks. Consider the following code:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def a():
   for i in range(0, 3):
      print('a.' + str(i))
      yield


@asyncio.coroutine
def b():
   for i in range(0, 3):
      print('b.' + str(i))
      yield


@asyncio.coroutine
def c():
   for i in range(0, 3):
      print('c.' + str(i))
      yield


tasks = [
   asyncio.Task(a()),
   asyncio.Task(b()),
   asyncio.Task(c()),
]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([t1, t2, t3]))
```

Running this will print:

```
a.0
b.0
c.0
a.1
b.1
c.1
a.2
b.2
c.2
```

Notice that it always prints out 'a' then 'b' then 'c'. I'm guessing that no matter how many iterations each coroutine goes through it will always print in that order. So you'd never see something like

```
b.100
c.100
a.100
```

Coming from a node.js background, this tells me that the event loop here is maintaining a queue internally that it uses to decide which task to run next. It initially puts `a()` at the front of the queue, then `b()`, then `c()` since that's the order of the tasks in the list passed to `asyncio.wait()`. Then whenever it hits a yield statement it puts that task at the end of the queue. I guess in a more realistic example, say if you were doing an async http request, it would put `a()` back on the end of the queue after the http response came back.

Can I get an amen on this?

Answer (score 4):

Currently your example doesn't include any blocking I/O code.  Try this to simulate some tasks:

```
import asyncio


@asyncio.coroutine
def coro(tag, delay):
    for i in range(1, 8):
        print(tag, i)
        yield from asyncio.sleep(delay)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

print("---- await 0 seconds :-) --- ")
tasks = [
    asyncio.Task(coro("A", 0)),
    asyncio.Task(coro("B", 0)),
    asyncio.Task(coro("C", 0)),
]

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))

print("---- simulate some blocking I/O --- ")
tasks = [
    asyncio.Task(coro("A", 0.1)),
    asyncio.Task(coro("B", 0.3)),
    asyncio.Task(coro("C", 0.5)),
]

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))

loop.close()
```

As you can see, coroutines are scheduled as needed, and not in order.

Comment: Right, it's going to run the callbacks as soon as it can so if the I/O takes different amounts of time to complete they will start to go out of order. My point was that if there was no I/O going on (as in my example) that they always run in a predictable order due to some kind of management of the tasks happening behind the scenes (possibly a queue). As opposed to something like threads which will run them according the OS thread scheduler and would be unpredictable.

Comment: If there is no I/O, don't use asyncio. They are not predictable, and you can't be sure how it will work in a different implementation or version, or under different conditions.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but my question wasn't about appropriate usage of `asyncio` but rather how it's implemented. Of course it's not safe to make assumptions about library implementation details, and I wasn't trying to imply otherwise by asking this question. Just wanted to see if anyone knew how it worked.

Comment: If you are interested in the implementation details, you can read Python 3.6's base implementation here, in [`BaseEventLoop._run_once`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1329).

Answer (score 3):

**DISCLAIMER** For at least v3.9 with the default implementation this appears to be true.  However, the inner workings of the event loop are not public interface and thus may be changed with new versions.  Additionally, asyncio allows for `BaseEventLoop` implementation to be substituted, which may change its behavior.

When a `Task` object is created, it calls `loop.call_soon` to register its `_step` method as a callback.  The `_step` method actually does the work of calling your coroutine with calls to `send()` and processing the results.

In `BaseEventLoop`, `loop.call_soon` places the `_step` callback at the end of a `_ready` list of callbacks.  Each run of the event loop, iterates the list of `_ready` callbacks in a FIFO order and calls them.  Thus, for the initial run of tasks, they are executed in the order they are created.

When the task `awaits` or `yield`s a future, it really depends on the nature of that future when the task's `_wakeup` method get put into the queue.

Also, note that other callbacks can be registered in between creation of tasks.  While it is true that if `TaskA` is created before `TaskB`, the initial run of `TaskA` will happen before `TaskB`, there could still be other callbacks that get run in between.

Last, the above behavior is also for the default `Task` class that comes with `asyncio`.  Its possible however to specify a custom task factory and use an alternative task implementation which could also change this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

(This is a follow up to D-Rock's answer, was too long to be a comment.)

The execution order of callbacks is guaranteed in the asyncio documentation in a few places.

The [`loop.call_soon()` docs guarantee the execution order](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon):

> Callbacks are called in the order in which they are registered. Each callback will be called exactly once.

The [`Future.add_done_callback()` docs specify that callbacks are scheduled via `loop.call_soon()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.add_done_callback), and thus have this guaranteed FIFO order.

And `asyncio.Task` described as a subclass of `asyncio.Future`, and so has the same behaviour for `add_done_callback()`.

So I think it's pretty safe to rely on FIFO ordering of asyncio callbacks, at least when using vanilla asyncio.

Comment: thanks!   but be warned... you should really use a limited queue when scheduling a large number of tasks based on user input. use of asyncio tasks as a "queue" can lead to oom situations and arbitrary "cancels" by the engine.

Comment: That's a good point, and also a more explicit way to control order!